# Socket.io Transport Unknown error. Everywhere

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, ejs

So, I've wrote a Web Dashboard for my public screenshot uploader. I've used socket.io combined with ejs to have dynamic content. I've also got an express backend serving the whole thing. Now that that's all cleared up, onto the issue.

After visiting 1 page with a socket.io connection then navigating to another (or the same location with a trailing slash) you receive a code: 0, transport error.

Edit: Currently using the latest version of socket.io, but older ones don't work either.

Extra Info:

Raw error: `{"code":0,"message":"Transport unknown"}`

Code: Very standard code, similar to what is used in the examples, initialized browserside using `io({ path: "" })`, serverside using `require("socket.io")(server, { path: "" })`, calls to the server using `socket.emit` and `socket.on`, nothing obvious that could possibly be throwing this error.

Other: No errors are emitted on the server, the client just receives that code as a response instead of any of the ejs that is supposed to be rendered. No errors are seen on the client console either.

Comment: please provide response, error log, code, etc.

Comment: @Dody Edited and explain as best I could. I can't give any more code because the issue is too non-specific. **Unless** you want me to link the service so you can investigate yourself.

Comment: Remove the two `path` properties from client and server.  Socket.io uses that to help it do its job.  Those are not needed at all and maybe causing you problems.

Comment: Without code, all people can do is make guesses.  Please include all relevant client and server code.

Comment: Hold on there @jfriend00 *takes off glasses*, I think you've fixed it. If you drop that as a solution, I will mark this as resolved. Thanks for helping me with what little info I gave.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the two `path` properties from client and server initialization. Socket.io uses that to help it do its job. Those are not needed at all and may be causing your problem.

Comment: I have the same problem but I need the path.

Comment: @Pietro - There is a way to control the path, but it needs matching client and server changes (so both are using the same path).  Please post your own question stating your precise problem.  99% of the time when people are messing with the path, it's because of a misunderstanding about how socket.io works and not because it's necessary.  You will need to explain your issue in your own question.

Comment: I found the problem and it's also the same of the main question. I did add the path to the root of the app. the path must be something different. for example by adding /{rootpath}/socket.io to the path it works.